# How to make correct pdfbookmarks for the nomenlature?

Tags: hyperref, nomenclature

In this example the pdfbookmark for the nomenclature is linked to the list of tables. How to make here the correct bookmark?

```
 \documentclass[listof=totoc,]{scrbook} 

 \usepackage{makeidx}
 \usepackage{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature  
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}

 \cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}\tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables

 \cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}\markboth{Nomenclature}{Nomenclature}
 \printnomenclature

 \chapter{Chapter One}
 Test\nomenclature{i.e.}{id est}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `nomencl` provides the option `intoc`. So you get the correct entry in the toc and the bookmark:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
 \documentclass[listof=totoc,]{scrbook} 

 \usepackage{makeidx}
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature  
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
 \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
 \tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables

\printnomenclature

 \chapter{Chapter One}
 Test\nomenclature{i.e.}{id est}

 \end{document}
```